# twitter typeahead shows all available values instead of just matching values

Tags: typeahead.js

I've tried applying twitters typeahead plugin in web application. I initiliaze a number of typeahead input fields with the typeahead plugin, which somehow seems to work. The plugin is brought to life. Id does however not seem to match the query string I'm writing with the values, that it chooses to display. If I for example choose to write 'Nuu', then it will also display values where first 3 letters are completely different.

My html looks like this:

And my JavaScript looks like this:

```
$(selector).each(function(){
  var jsonUrl = $(this).attr('data-json');
    $(this).typeahead({
      name : 'berths',
      remote : {
      url : jsonUrl,
      filter : myfilter
    }
  });
});


myfilter = function(parsedResponse) {
  var datums = $.map(parsedResponse, function(berth) {
    var datum = {
      name : berth.name,
      value : berth.name + (berth.alias ? " (" + berth.alias + ")" : ""),
      tokens : [ berth.name, berth.alias ],
      latitude : berth.latitude,
      longitude : berth.longitude
    };

    return datum;
  });

  return datums;
};
```

Any clues to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While typeahead.js will filter local and prefetch data for a given query, it will not filter the remote data. typeahead.js operates under the assumption that, for remote data, filtering is done server-side.

It seems like using prefetch may be a better option for your use case:

```
$(selector).typeahead({
  name : 'berths',
  prefetch : {
    url : jsonUrl,
    filter : myfilter
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had previously tried using prefetch, which were never executed due to another error. This confused me a bit. I however now have it working using a combination of prefetch and remote, which suites my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing query data on the `jsonUrl`?  TypeAhead requires a replacement string in the URL to replace with the data typed in the field, so the URL should look like:

```
/my/data/source/?text=%QUERY
```

where the `%QUERY` is replaced with the input field contents.

Note that `%QUERY` is the default; you should be able to use any string you wish, but I have not yet been able to get that to work.